# How to detect which dropdown was clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 this HTML blocks for each dropdown:

```js
//And this JS code:

$( document.body ).on( 'click', '.dropdown-menu li', function( event ) {
var $target = $( event.currentTarget );

$target.closest( '.btn-group' )
    .find( '[data-bind="label2"]' ).text( $target.text() )
    .end()
    .children( '.dropdown-toggle' ).dropdown( 'toggle' );

return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span data-bind="label">Select One</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another item</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

The problem is, I do not know which of these dropdowns was selected. Is there any solution to distinguish which dropdown value was changed, first or second one?

Comment: can you give the dropdowns unique IDs? Or a "data-x" attribute with some info in? You could then use that to identify it.

Comment: @Dij Don't make something a snippet if it doesn't even run

Comment: As ADyson mentioned, if you give both your `.btn-group` elements an id. Then you can check `$target.closest( '.btn-group' )[0].id`

Comment: No it doesn't, you get an error when you click the `<li>`s `"Uncaught TypeError: $target.closest(...).find(...).text(...).end(...).children(...).dropdown is not a function` The plugin for dropdown is not being included. Also, your example should have two dropdowns since that's what your question is about. Lastly, it doesn't even display like a dropdown... To say it another way, your snippet needs to show the problem, it does not even show a working dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is some:

I like d to obtain the index, and work with this it, obtain anything with this.

```
 var _index = 0;
    $( document.body ).on( 'click', '.dropdown-menu li', function( event ) {
_index =$(this).index();

    return false;
    });
```

You can return anytime with this:

```
var selected = $('.dropdown-menu li:eq('+_index+')');
```

And get what to togle will this

```
$target.closest( '.btn-group' )
    .find( '[data-bind="label2"]' ).text( $target.text() )
    .end()
    .children( '.dropdown-menu li:eq('+_index+')' ).dropdown( 'toggle' );
```

Comment: That will be the index of the li that was clicked within the drop down. The OP wants to know which of the two dropdowns was clicked

Comment: I re-edited, to response more concrete. expect was it